# writing two Non Null values in two rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I looking for efficient way to split the values in a row into two when there is non null values in column A and column B

[image]

[image]

Comment: input image is created through lot of joins and nested queries

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images. (Can't copy-and-paste from images...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT output, col3
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  output FOR key IN (cola, colb)
)
```

Or, replace `table_name` with `()` brackets containing your query.
Which, for the sample data:

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (cola, colb, col3) AS
SELECT LEVEL, CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN 6 END, CHR(64+LEVEL) || CHR(64 + LEVEL)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Outputs:

> | OUTPUT | COL3 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | AA |
> | 2 | BB |
> | 6 | BB |
> | 3 | CC |
> | 4 | DD |
> | 5 | EE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fceb220b1474a01f8f92cc1b1cdb52f)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; union two sets, return only those whose `cola` is not empty.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb, colc) as
  2    (select 1, null, 'AA' from dual union all
  3     select 2,    6, 'BB' from dual union all
  4     select 3, null, 'CC' from dual union all
  5     select 4, null, 'DD' from dual union all
  6     select 5, null, 'EE' from dual
  7    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  temp as
  9    (select cola, colc from test
 10     union all
 11     select colb, colc from test
 12    )
 13  select cola, colc
 14  from temp
 15  where cola is not null
 16  order by colc, cola;

      COLA COLC
---------- ----------
         1 AA
         2 BB
         6 BB
         3 CC
         4 DD
         5 EE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

You commented that the "input" is result of many joins and nested queries; no problem - just use that *complicated* query as a CTE:

```
with test as
  (your complicated query with joins and nested queries goes here),
temp as 
   the rest is copy/paste from above
```